sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class, consider adding relationship() after dependent classes have been defined
I'm currently working on integrating SQLAlchemy into my project to handle database interactions. However, I'm encountering an InvalidRequestError when trying to map relationships between classes. Below is a detailed description of my setup and the issue I'm facing:
Background:
I'm using SQLAlchemy in a Python project to interact with a MySQL database.
I have two classes, Place and Review, which have a one-to-many relationship. Each place can have multiple reviews associated with it.
Code Overview:
I have defined the Place and Review classes as follows:
# Place class
class Place(BaseModel, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'places'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Other attributes...

    reviews = relationship("Review", backref="place", cascade="all, delete")

# Review class
class Review(BaseModel, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    place_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('places.id'))
    # Other attributes...

#in BaseModel Class

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

if models.storage_t == "db":
    Base = declarative_base()
else:
    Base = object


class BaseModel:
    """A base class for all hbnb models"""
    id = Column(String(60), primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''the constructor'''
        if kwargs:
            if len(kwargs) == 0:
              # Rest of constructor


Problem Description:
When I run my application, I encounter the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Place->places, expression 'Review' failed to locate a name ('Review'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.place.Place'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.


Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
What I've Tried:
I have checked for circular import issues by ensuring that classes are imported correctly.
I have reviewed the SQLAlchemy documentation and other resources but haven't found a solution yet.

Are both model classes in the same file? If not, Review must be imported into the module in which it is referenced.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
